# What is the value for rwSrwSrwT?

Tags: permissions, chmod

The value `1777` is the permission of `rwxrwxrwt`:

```
touch target.txt
chmod 1777 target.txt
ls -al  target.txt
-rwxrwxrwt 1 debian debian 0 Jul 14 20:24 target.txt
```

I have to get a permission string of `rwSrwSrwT`:

```
ls -al  sample
-rwSrwSrwT 1 debian debian 0 Jul 14 20:24 sample
```

How can calculate the value for `rwSrwSrwT` then?

Comment: The answers (at this time) are correct but you might want to note that setting suid on a directory doesn't do anything. sgid changes the group of the file created assuming the creator is in the same group. If suid set the owner then users could give away files but not take them back. It would also break disk quotas if they are in effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to find out:

```
#↳ touch file
#↳ chmod a=rw,ug+s,+t file
#↳ stat file
  File: file
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 803h/2051d      Inode: 5131644     Links: 1
Access: (7666/-rwSrwSrwT)  Uid: ( 1000/ cad)   Gid: ( 1000/ cad)
Access: 2023-07-15 20:56:08.363457855 +0100
Modify: 2023-07-15 20:56:08.363457855 +0100
Change: 2023-07-15 20:56:16.583445800 +0100
 Birth: 2023-07-15 20:56:08.363457855 +0100
```

Answer is on line 4 from `stat`.

Answer (score 4):

The direct answer to your question is `7666`.

```
$ chmod 7666 target.txt

$ ls -l target.txt 
-rwSrwSrwT 1 svsv svsv 0 Jul 14 13:20 target.txt
```

The most significant digit in the 4-digit mode affects the setuid (`---S------`), setgid (`------S---`) and the sticky (`---------T`) bits. They're marked in the same positions as the `x` bits, and the upper `S` or `T` indicates the corresponding `x` bit is *not* set.

This could serve as a reference example:

```
0000    =   ----------
0111    =   ---x--x--x
1000    =   ---------T
1111    =   ---x--x--t
2000    =   ------S---
2111    =   ---x--s--x
 ...    =   ...
7000    =   ---S--S--T
7111    =   ---s--s--t
7666    =   -rwSrwSrwT
7777    =   -rwsrwsrwt
```

Answer (score 0):

`rwSrwSrwT` means:

- read, write, setUID and not-execute for User
- read, write, setGID and not-execute for Group
- read, write, sticky and not-execute for Others

so the octal value you're looking for is 7666:

`chmod 7666 target.txt`

Reference table:

[image]

Note that you could just copy the permission value from one file to another, without bothering to calculate the octal value:

`chmod --reference=sample target.txt`